# How can I detect any unicode characters which have descenders, using .NET

Tags: unicode, typography

I am trying to minimize the vertical distance between controls on a programmatically constructed Windows Form (using C#).  This involves setting the Height property appropriately.

I have found that if the text of the control does not contain any letters with descenders in them (i.e. does not have any of the characters j, g, p, q or y) then the control Height can be smaller than when it does contain such letters (if it *does* contain letters with descenders then the descenders are chopped off if the Height isn't enough).

It will work fine to test for any of the above 5 characters as long as the language is English, or English - like, but I need to be able to cater for (just about) any language.

Is there a way, given some arbitrary Unicode character (and perhaps a font) to determine if that Unicode character has a descender or not?

Comment: H̡̫̤̤̣͉̤ͭ̓̓̇͗̎̀ơ̯̗̱̘̮͒̄̀̈ͤ̀͡w͓̲͙͖̥͉̹͋ͬ̊ͦ̂̀̚ ͎͉͖̌ͯͅͅd̳̘̿̃̔̏ͣ͂̉̕ŏ̖̙͋ͤ̊͗̓͟͜e͈͕̯̮̙̣͓͌ͭ̍̐̃͒s͙͔̺͇̗̱̿̊̇͞ ̸̤͓̞̱̫ͩͩ͑̋̀ͮͥͦ̊Z̆̊͊҉҉̠̱̦̩͕ą̟̹͈̺̹̋̅ͯĺ̡̘̹̻̩̩͋͘g̪͚͗ͬ͒o̢̖͇̬͍͇͓̔͋͊̓ ̢͈͙͂ͣ̏̿͐͂ͯ͠t̛͓̖̻̲ͤ̈ͣ͝e͋̄ͬ̽͜҉͚̭͇ͅx͎̬̠͇̌ͤ̓̂̓͐͐́͋͡ț̗̹̝̄̌̀ͧͩ̕͢ ̮̗̩̳̱̾w͎̭̤͍͇̰̄͗ͭ̃͗ͮ̐o̢̯̻̰̼͕̾ͣͬ̽̔̍͟ͅr̢̪͙͍̠̀ͅǩ̵̶̗̮̮ͪ́?̙͉̥̬͙̟̮͕ͤ̌͗ͩ̕͡

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no property defined for Unicode characters to indicate the presence of a descender, and it’s really a feature of glyph design rather than characters. For example, “Q” has a descenders in many fonts, and “J” has one in some. Besides, given the context, you should also consider diacritic marks placed below a letter, not just descenders of base letters. And probably diacritics *above* letters, too.

So you would need to read the font information (when available) about character dimensions, or tentatively draw characters in your software and measure their dimensions.

As a rule of thumb, any line height below 1.1 times the font size will cause problems with some characters and fonts. Using 1 (“setting solid”) is not enough, because characters may in fact extend outside the font size.

Comment: Thanks for the rule of thumb.  I'll try to arrive at some happy medium somehow.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, you call GetPath() to get an array containing the X/Y coordinates of every point making up the perimeter or outline of the string of glyphs. Search the array for min/max, which will get you the rectangle *exactly* enclosing the string. Right to the edge of the letters.